# Placing an object with 3-4 node(corner) of 3D object (c# unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit

there is any way to place object with three point? I have three or four point (xyz position) in (world) real world ( i know this points) and I want to place(instantiate) my new object to inside this coordinates bestly.

I tired to place the object correctly, but there is no good result.

Edit:

A B C D points will be corner of cuboid object(for example; brick).
Need to find position, rotation and set scale of **CuboidObjectToPlace** for place brick to insert into A B C D .

[cuboid object with 4 corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sH53m.png)

I want to create an object that is cuboid object (I created it as prefab in asset folder).
I know three corner in real world. i created objects at this points named leftSphere, rightSphere, topSphere, backSphere.
How can i find center(position) and rotation for place my cuboid prefab.

```
public List<Transform> positions;
public GameObject cubloidObjectPrefabToPlace;

private GameObject topSphere; // A corner of real cuboid object in real world
private GameObject leftSphere; // B corner of real cuboid object in real world
private GameObject rightSphere; // C corner of real cuboid object in real world
private GameObject backSphere; // D corner of real cuboid object in real world
```

..

```
void Update(){

    findCornersInRealWorld(); // found corners and 
                              //placed A, B, C, D objects

    positions.Add(leftSphere.transform);
    positions.Add(rightSphere.transform);
    positions.Add(topSphere.transform);
    positions.Add(backSphere.transform);



    createAtCenter();         // Want to implement here..
}
```

..

```
void createAtCenter()
{
    float x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
    foreach (Transform p in positions)
    {
        x += p.position.x;
        y += p.position.y;
        z += p.position.z;
    }

    x /= positions.Count;
    y /= positions.Count;
    z /= positions.Count;
    Vector3 pos = new Vector3(x, y, z);

    Instantiate(cubloidObjectPrefabToPlace, pos, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

Comment: Please add your code. Could you please explain this further .. what does `place ... bestly` mean here? It would probably help to also see some screenshots of the behaviour you expect.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I suppose you want to place the object at the center of n given points.
   `public List<Transform> positions;
    public GameObject obj;

    void createAtCenter()
   {
       float x=0, y=0, z=0;
       foreach (Transform p in positions)
        {
            x += p.position.x;
            y += p.position.y;
            z += p.position.z;
        }
        x /= positions.Count;
        y /= positions.Count;
        z /= positions.Count;
        Vector3 pos = new Vector3(x, y, z);
        Instantiate(obj,pos,Quaternion.identity);
    }`

Comment: @SaraKat yes I want to place the my prefab that I have this object in asset.  I 've  tried this solution but it's not created my object at center. Need to calculate scale and rotation?

Comment: It is simplier to write `Vector3 center = Vector3.zero; foreach (var trans in positions) { center += trans.position; } center /= positions.Count;`

Comment: I have tried this code. and placed incorrectly. I found corner point with touch on run time. so we don't know dimension of cuboid object. So I guess need to scale and rotate it.  
   edit:    { positions.Add(cylinderX.transform);
              positions.Add(cylinderY.transform);
              positions.Add(cylinderZ.transform);    } .  @derHugo

Answer (score 0):

So I have a cuboid object in scene, I know edges point and corner points. I want to place a cuboid object(in asset) instead of old cuboid object exactly same position, rotation and scale. How can I set scale, rotate and position of object's

```
positions.Add(edge1.transform);
positions.Add(edge2.transform);
positions.Add(edge3.transform);
positions.Add(edge4.transform);
positions.Add(edge5.transform);
positions.Add(edge6.transform);
positions.Add(edge7.transform);
positions.Add(edge8.transform);
```

setting scale?

```
cubloidObjectPrefabToPlace.transform.localScale = new Vector3(
                               edge1.transform.localScale.x, 
                               edge2.transform.localScale.y, 
                               edge3.transform.localScale.z);
```

set position?

```
Vector3 center = Vector3.zero;

foreach (var trans in positions)
{
    center += trans.position;

}
center /= positions.Count;
```

rotation ??

```
Instantiate(cubloidObjectPrefabToPlace, center, Quaternion.identity);
```

Still incorrect position, rotation and incorrect scale